# Relationship b/w spin-0 and complex scalar field

Tags: field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, antimatter, complex-numbers

Why do the complex scalar fields defined using two sets of creation and annihilation operators (one for particle and one for antiparticle) describe spin-0?
Is it because that they originated from scalar QED in which $e^-$'s spin is neglected?

Comment: Are you asking why a field with 2 sets of creation/annihilation operators describes a spin-0 particle as opposed to a higher-spin particle?  Note that spin-0 particles are adequately described by real scalar fields; complex scalar fields describe charged spin-0 particles.

Comment: I am wondering why it describes spin particles at all.

Comment: And to your comment, why are spin 0 particles described by real scalar fields? And the complex scalar fields is the real scalar fields plus photons?

Comment: First off, by "scalar" what is really meant is "Lorentz scalar"; that is, a field that is invariant with respect to Lorentz transformations.  Rotations are a subset of Lorentz transformation: if a field is unchanged by a rotation, it cannot have spin (which has a direction).  Therefore, a field is spin-0 if and only if it is a Lorentz scalar.

A complex scalar field still only describes spin-0 particles (photons are spin-1, or vectors under Lorentz).  The additional imaginary degrees of freedom of the complex field are manifested as charge.